# @interface and multiple class names Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, interface

**Original question**

I have a class named RootViewController and my .h file has the code below

```
#import "SEViewController.h"


@interface RootViewController : SEViewController{

}
@end
```

and my SEViewController looks like

```
@interface SEViewController : UIViewController
{
}

@end
```

How can i declare RootViewController as UITableViewController and also as SEViewController the same time?

---

**Edited question**

Now I have the code below, but I get warnings and the table view does not appear.

RootViewController.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ApplicationCell.h"
#import "SEViewController.h"


@interface RootViewController : SEViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *tableView;
    ApplicationCell *tmpCell;
    NSArray *data;
}
@property (copy) NSArray *data;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

RootViewController.m:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "SubviewApplicationCell.h"


#define DARK_BACKGROUND  [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor]
#define LIGHT_BACKGROUND [UIColor clearColor];


@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize data;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View controller methods


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rules" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"rules";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 73.0;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = DARK_BACKGROUND;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.data = nil;
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ApplicationCell";

    ApplicationCell *cell = (ApplicationCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[[SubviewApplicationCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }



    cell.arrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"];
    cell.name = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell.backgroundColor =  LIGHT_BACKGROUND;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:nil animated:YES];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc
{
    [data release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: You can't use `tableView` in `viewDidLoad`. So, either this code doesn't compile, or you are not showing your real code. Try using `self.tableView`instead.

Comment: Of course it's my real code it compiles fine but i get 2 warnings

Comment: GRRRRR not working, i'm gonna kill my self...

Comment: Now is my whole root view controller file .m and .h too

Comment: please take a look again i edited all my files and i don't get an error if i use tableView instead of self.tableView

Comment: OHHHH shit now i removed self. i get error stupid xcode the error says "use of undeclared indetifier do you mean _tableView"

Comment: See my edited answer. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: still the table not appear. i can see the background so but no cells

Comment: This should probably be in another question. The current question is now very different from the original one. Even the answers below look like if they respond to a different question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8346/discussion-between-mpampinos-holmens-and-sch)

Comment: ok i got into chat sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you make

```
@interface SEViewController : UITableViewController
{

}
```

Or, create SEViewController as UIViewController, put a table on it, and implement the UITableViewDelegate, and you are going to have the same.

```
@interface SEViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

}
```

For creating and adding a table to your view, use this code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect totalFrame = self.view.frame;
    UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:totalFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
    [myTableView release];

}
```

Comment: i can't do the first one because i load some UIViews too so i can't see the views then

Comment: On the second one i can't see the table also i get 2 warnings "local declaration of tableview hides instance variable"

Comment: You need to create a new table in the ViewDidLoad, put it in your view and assignate the delegate and the datasource to self

Comment: thanks i think i managed to get it working! Thanks for all your help man.

Answer (score 3):

Objective C doesn't support multiple inheritance. So `RootViewController` can't be a subclass of both `SEViewController` and `UITableViewController`.

However, you can make `RootViewController` conform to the protocols : `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, and implement the corresponding methods.

```
@interface RootViewController : SEViewController < UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

// tableView declaration;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;

// ...
@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

// ...
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     // ...
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
     // ...
}
// ...
```

**Edit** After you showed your complete code, I think the problem is here:

```
@interface RootViewController : SEViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *tableView; // Remove this line
    ApplicationCell *tmpCell;
    NSArray *data;
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that but then i can't load a common UIView it just not apperaing.

Comment: in methods - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 and - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 i get warning that says local decleration of tableview hides instance variable. and then my table view just not appear

Comment: How do you declare the `tableView`? Try synthesizing it using `@synthesize tableView = _tableView;`.

Comment: i can see the background of my table view but the table it self not appears

Comment: Did you declare a property tableView in `RootViewController` or in `SEViewController`? I Edited my answer to show that.

Comment: The property tableView is conflicting with the parameter tableView in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Rename one of them.

Comment: nope, i can't figure what is going on... the problem still remains

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is not possible in objective-c ,all you can do is to incorporate table view in SEViewController and declare delegate methods in it.. hoping this helps....

Answer (score 1):

You can only inherit from one parent class, but it sounds like you just want to do...

```
@interface RootViewController : SEViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
```